# Npm / Yarn : how to filter files copied from local path dependencies?

Tags: npm, phoenix-framework, yarnpkg

I have a weird behavior in a phoenix project.

The project defines dependencies to local projects:

```
"dependencies": {
  "phoenix": "file:../../deps/phoenix",
  "phoenix_html": "file:../../deps/phoenix_html",
  ...
```

Both `npm install` and `yarn install` are able to locate the projects and copy the files in "node_modules". However :

- `npm install` only copies a subset of the "deps/phoenix" folder (mostly `.js` files)
- `yarn install` copies the whole folder (both `.js` and `.ex` files)

How does `npm` knows which files to copy ? Is it simply a convention ? I did not find anything particular in "deps/phoenix/package.json", for example.

Otherwise, is there a way to have `yarn` behave the same as `npm` ?

Comment: From my experience I guess `npm` does this by looking at certain fields inside `package.json`, e.g. `main`, `types` and `files`.
But it also figures out some other files like `README.md`.

If you take a look at the file `node_modules/dependency/package.json` you will find some additional fields when comparing to the original `package.json` e.g. `readmeFilename` which points to the also copied file.

That is all I know, that's why this is just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a "file" option that npm uses, but yarn has a bug about it. I'm going to close the question as too localised.

Comment: Is there an open issue for it? And which one is it? Would love to know when it is fixed ...

Comment: I added https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2822 to track this.